# Database to PDF

Tags: xslt, pdf, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, pdf-form

I have a database that contains data that I want to use to populate a "page" (this page is a document that has been styled in Adobe InDesign -- but could be another software -- and has placeholders for various data). The page will be printed.

What technology would be best suited for this job? Should I create a PDF form and populate the fields from the database? Note that there are some data that is "loopable" (e.g. a list of products that have product name, description, price -- and the list may be 0 or more up to a set max number). Should I be looking at something like XSL-FO instead? Or some other solution?

Comment: There are as many solutions as questions and everyone that answers will only impart their bias/knowledge of the solutions they know. is that what you are asking for?

Answer (score 2):

How about [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library).

You can export a Jasper report in HTML format in order to populate the page.

Thereafter, you can export it in PDF, CSV, Excel...

Answer (score 0):

@user3426114's suggestion of JasperReports is a valid one, it's just that in my opinion creating "pixel perfect" versions of an example page is not entirely trivial, but that may be very well due to my inexperience with the product or some PEBKAC type issue :)

As an alternative, assuming you can get (more easily) to a state where the document displays correctly in a browser (using whatever page creation technique you are familiar with, ranging from JSP over php and asp.net to RoR) you could use [HTMLDoc](http://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1) to have that page converted to a pdf.

Yet another alternative could be [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), a headless Webkit implementation. According to [their documentation](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html), rendering a page from the command line as a pdf is as simple as

```
phantomjs rasterize.js 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jakarta&printable=yes' jakarta.pdf
```

This last alternative has the great advantage of actually running the Javascript on the page, thereby making correct rendering of elements that receive their style via a script that runs on page load possible, something which as far as I know HTMLDoc doesn't do - it'll just render css+html